# как выборочно сохранять данные из ответа формата json в Postman

Tags: postman

Я отправляю запрос через постман, и получаю ответ в формате json, как мне сохранить конкретное поле по определенному ключу?
Пример ответа:

```
 {
            "uuid": "0#####17-###-####-####-a9#####0f5fc",
            "price": {
                "amount": "4974.49",
                "currency": "RUB"
            },
            "flights": [
                4
            ],
            "alliance": "SkyTeam",
            "price_per_pax": {
                "adult": {
                    "amount": "4974.49",
                    "currency": "RUB"
                },
                "child": null,
                "infant": null
            },
            "validating_carrier": "SU",
            "refundable": false
        }
```

Из этого ответа мне надо сохранить UUID, т.к. у него идет alliance "SkyTeam" (а альянсы могут меняться, но мне нужен именно SkyTeam)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set("uuid", data.payload.offers[0].uuid);
for (var i = 1; i < data.payload.offers.length; i++){ 
    pm.environment.set("uuid" + i, data.payload.offers[i].uuid);
}
```

И эти значения сохранились у меня в пространстве переменных постмана